# Solr 5 incompatible schema.xml

Tags: search

An error kept showing after installing Search API for solr and after creating a server on drupal. (Solr 5.x)

***You are using an incompatible schema.xml configuration file. Please follow the instructions in the handbook for setting up Solr.***

Already copied alll configuration files from drupal module into:
/opt/solr/server/solr/my-core/conf

what else to check?

Comment: What OS? Solr on Centos uses `/var/solr/data/[core]` by default.

Comment: Am using Centos 7. So i have to override whats in /var/solr/data/[core] with  drupal config file!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Centos systems Solr assumes your cores will be stored in `/var/solr/data/[core-name]`.

So if your core is named `my-core`, Solr might already have created the folder `/var/solr/data/my-core` for you. Simply place the `conf` directory in that folder, overwriting anything that might already be in `conf`.
No need to touch any of the other files.

Comment: Great, if you click the check-icon next to question, it will be marked as solved :)

Comment: I have the same error on ubuntu,how can I fix that?

Comment: Read the solr documentation for your os. Learn where it stores the data. I knew this becasue I use centos myself.